# Can't assign ObjectContext.ObjectMaterialized event in DbContext Constructor

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this constructor on a Code First DbContext:

```
    public MillCATContext() : base("Name=MillCAT") {

      ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ObjectMaterialized +=
              (sender, e) => DateTimeKindAttribute.Apply(e.Entity);

      Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
      Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

    }
```

The problem occurs only in design time when I tried to open a VS2012 user control that has the creation of the context in a protected field in it.

I get the error

> "No connection string named 'MillCAT' could by found in the
>   application config file."

So, where can I assigned this event to avoid this problem.

By the way I can run the project without any problem.

Just to let you know, the DbContext (MillCATContext) is in project A, the POCO model in Project B, and the user control in winform project C.  My connection string is defined in app.config of project A and C.

Comment: post your web/app.config connectionstrings!

Comment: @Ahmed <add name="MillCAT" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\Projects;Initial Catalog=MillCAT;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />